# reusable components in react.js

Tags: reactjs

how to create a page with two reusable components and third "controller" component that will provide two-way communication with the first two. 
Component 1 & 2 will be simple text boxes that will show the text value character count next to them. Component 3 will be a read-only textbox that will show the sum of the counts of 1&2.

Below is the code for the same.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.jsx"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
</div>
<div id="container2">
</div>
    <input type="text" id="Final" name="finaltextbox"/>
<script type="text/babel">
        var max_chars = 0;
        var App = 
                    React.createClass({
                                        render: function() {
                                                            return (
                                                                    <div> <TwitterInput /> </div>
                                                                   );
                                                            }
                                     });

        var TwitterInput = 
             React.createClass({
                    getInitialState: 
                          function() {
                                                return {
                                                chars_left: max_chars
                                                };
                                                },
                                                handleChange(event) {
                                                var input = event.target.value;
                                                this.setState({
                                                chars_left: input.length 
                                                });
                                                },
                                                render: function() {
                                                return (
                                                <div>
                                                    <textarea onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}></textarea>
                                                    <p> {this.state.chars_left}</p>
                                                </div>
                                                );
                                         }
                             });

        ReactDOM.render(
        <App />,
        document.getElementById('container')
        );
        ReactDOM.render(
        <App />,
        document.getElementById('container2')
        );

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's your question? If it's "how do I do this" - that's way too broad for StackOverflow. Narrow your question down to the specific thing you're having trouble with at the minute, and ask about that (preferably including your code). See ["How to Ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info.

Comment: I want to create reusable components using react.js which will show the text count next to them and a third component which will show the total input count of first two components. all components would be textfields

Comment: Use refs so the third Component (the parent) get the values of first and second component ? As @joe said, be more precise with you question

Comment: @Nevosis: [You shouldn't use refs for parent/child component communication](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#dont-overuse-refs) - see [Lifting State Up](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html) from the React docs.